# Pattern Inventory of Tetrahedron

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Determine the pattern inventory of the 3 colorings of a floating tetrahedron.

Workings:

\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{cycles} & \text{cycle structure}\\ 
\hline
(1)(2)(3)(4) &  x_1^4\\ 
(1)(234) & x_1x_3 \\ 
(1)(243) & x_1x_3 \\ 
(2)(134) & x_1x_3 \\
(2)(143) & x_1x_3 \\
(3)(124) & x_1x_3 \\
(3)(142) & x_1x_3 \\
(4)(123) & x_1x_3 \\
(4)(132) & x_1x_3 \\
(12)(34) & x_2^2 \\
(13)(24) & x_2^2 \\
(14)(23) & x_2^2  
\end{array}

This gives the cycle index:

$P_G = \frac{1}{12}(x_1^4 + 8x_1x_3 + 3x_2^2)$

So the Polya's formula is:

$P_G = \frac{1}{12}[(b+w+r)^4 + 8(b+w+r)(b+w+r) + 3(b+w+r)^2]$

$P_G = \frac{1}{12}[(b+w+r)^4 + 11(b+w+r)^2]$

However I believe that if I divide the following I will get non-integer solutions which I don't think makes sense. So I don't know what I id wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your cycle index is essentially the identity, plus rotations about an axis passing through a vertex and the center of the opposite face, plus 180 degree flips that fix two opposite edges, and is correct. There is a mistake in your substitution for $x_3$ however. Your cycle index gives $$\frac{1}{12}\left(N^4+11N^2\right)$$ as the number of colorings with at most $N$ colors and this points to [OEIS A006008](https://oeis.org/A006008), which is correct also.

Comment: You seem to have overlooked that the substitution rule here is $x_k = b^k+w^k+r^k.$

Comment: Right I forgot about that rule. Thanks for the help.